# Why is my custom post content only viewable when signed into Wordpress?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, posts, customization, post-type

I've created a custom Post type called 'Data' to display content on a Wordpress site. The content works and is displayed if viewed when signed into Wordpress. Howevever, if you view the same URL when not signed into Wordpress *(Incognito)*, the page appears blank. Is there a soultion to this?

[image: Custom Post Type]

Snippet from functions.php:

```
// Our custom post type function
```

function create_posttype() {

```
register_post_type( 'Data',
// CPT Options
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Data' ),
            'singluar_name' => 'Data',
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('with_front' => false, 'slug' => 'data'),
        'support' => array('title', 'editor'),
        'publicly_queryable' => true

    )
);
```

}
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! You'll need to share the code you used to register the CPT in order for anyone to be able to help identify the reason it's not showing for everyone. It's likely that you either registered the CPT as not public, or else set it up with capabilities (even for reading) that mean if you're not logged in as a user with the `read_{cptslug}` capability you won't be able to see the content.

Comment: Thanks WebElaine, I've updated the question with a snippet of code from our functions.php file that may be of help. If there's anything else I can post, please let me know.

Comment: You might try changing that first line to use a lowercase slug of `data` instead of `Data`. That could be confusing WP as everything is case-sensitive and normally slugs are all lowercase. Then once you make changes you'll definitely need to visit the Settings > Permalinks page to refresh permalinks, and possibly also need to run `unregister_post_type()` right before `register_post_type()` (just once, then you can remove the unregister call) as settings can get cached pretty hard.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by “blank”? A completely white screen? Or just the content is missing?